# PHPSpreadsheet: Putting/Showing multiple spaces (whitespace/indentation) in a cell

Tags: php, excel, whitespace, spaces, phpspreadsheet

I'm using \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html() to read an HTML table to save into an XLSX spreadsheet.  I need indentation on some rows, for example it should appear like this:

```
Cost of Sales
  Stock
  Courier Fees
```

In the HTML table it's easy using **&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;**, but this doesn't take those multiple spaces into the Excel cells.  I've tried "   " (multiple spaces) and **<td style='padding-left:10px;'>** and even **<td style='margin-left:10px;'>** just in case, all to no avail.  I can't find anything on Google to assist and would appreciate any advice.

Just in case, I'll include how I'm reading/writing the HTML table stored in $incomeStatement:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($incomeStatement);
// [headers]
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$spreadsheet->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

use combination with html tag `span` followed by space like sample below

```html
<span>&nbsp;</span> <span>&nbsp;</span> <span>&nbsp;</span> <span>&nbsp;</span>
```

this example will make 4 spaces